# Looking for the title of a sci-fi book about small people living underground in tunnels

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the Title of a science fiction book about people who were small in stature and live underground in tunnels.  They fear and fight rats and live off eating worms
It has been a while and I may be forgetting things.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Share with us anything you can.  For example when was it written?  When did you read it?

Comment: In addition to CHEESE's questions, [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/22078) are some more tips for improving the chances of finding your story.

Comment: It sounds like "The Borrowers" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borrowers),  but I seem to have a dim recollection of another tale. Maybe it will surface at some point and I can enter a real Answer.

Comment: I thought of "The Borrowers" too but I don't think they ate worms.

Answer (score 4):

Might be [*The Hero of Downways*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3199832-the-hero-of-downways) by Michael G Coney. It certainly features people who have been genetically engineered to be very small, and live in tunnels. The Hero of the title became a hero by killing a rat (called the Daggertooth). I can't find any reference to them eating worms without actually reading the book.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still looking for it, but it sounds like you're talking about [**The Borribles**](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/585265) by  Michael de Larrabeiti.

> What is a Borrible? Borribles are runaways who dwell in the shadows of
> London. Apart from their pointed ears, they look just like ordinary
> children. They live by their wits and a few Borrible laws-the chief
> one being, Don't Get Caught! The Borribles are outcasts-but they
> wouldn't have it any other way....
>
> One night, the Borribles of Battersea discover a Rumble-one of the
> giant, rat-shaped creatures who are their ancient enemy-in their
> territory. Fearing an invasion, an elite group of Borrible fighters
> set out on what will become known in legend as The Great Rumble Hunt.
> So begins the first of the three epic adventures in Michael de
> Larrabeiti's classic trilogy, where excitement, violence, low cunning,
> greed, generosity, treachery, and bravery exist side by side.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please could you add some information about this story, like a link or a synopsis or anything so that people reading your post can judge how closely it fits what the OP describes? See also [how to write a good story-ID answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/31394).